# How passing data with multiple prepareforsegue in a uitableviewcell swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a UItableViewCell and depending the text in the cell I want to go to another uitableviewcontroller and pass some data to it. I already try this with performseguewithidentifier but this method doesn't pass data.

Comment: Check Out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315133/swift-pass-uitableviewcell-label-to-new-viewcontroller ) it will answer your queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this [How to pass prepareForSegue: an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864371/how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-an-object)

In the sender object you can put any object and in the prepareforsegue you can set the object of your second view controller.