# Passing data from tableviewcell to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to pass cell's tag data to another viewcontroller's variable

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
       print(currentCell.tag)
        valueToPass = currentCell.tag


    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


        let Dest  = segue.destinationViewController as! EventDetail

        if (segue.identifier == "eDetay") {

        Dest.eventid = String(valueToPass)
        }

    }
```

When i try as it is, `valueToPass` is always passed the previous data.

Is there a way to get selected cell data from `prepareForSegue` ?

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Could you share your UITableView Datasource method?

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the indexPath parameter that is being passed to you.

Remove the first let statement. Use the indexPath that is being passed to you.

Comment: Yeah i removed but still cannot pass the current data

Comment: Did removing that help at all? Or is it doing exactly the same thing?

Comment: Exactly same thing

Comment: Is there a way to get selected cell data from prepareForSegue ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought for sure that was it. Everything else you are doing looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes. See Rob's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315133/swift-pass-uitableviewcell-label-to-new-viewcontroller

Comment: One thing that i can't understand on Rob's answer. items[selectedRow] what is that items array ? how can i get the cell's tag data ?

Comment: You don't have an items array. You are using the tag property as your model. So -- in Rob's second example, after let cell = sender as UITableViewCell, you can just use cell.tag, if your segue is wired up from the cell. Also, notice that if you are using prepareForSegue, then you don't need to use didSelectRowForIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)

{
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as YourCell

//cell.value, cell.text, cell.randomValue or whatever you need
}