# did not get passed value from tableView in second ViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I read other post in stackoverflow to find answer but I cannot find the answer why I cannot get passed value in second ViewController.

In first ViewController, I generate tableView value:

```
func loadInitialData() {
    todoItems = [
        TodoItem(itemName: "www.google.com"),
        TodoItem(itemName: "www.bing.com")
    ]
}
```

and inside tableView I generate sent parameter to second ViewController:

```
var valueToPass:String!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

    let tappedItem = todoItems[indexPath.row] as TodoItem
    let linkURL: String! = todoItems[indexPath.row].itemName
    tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
    valueToPass = linkURL
    print("value to pass:"+valueToPass)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("lemparURL", sender: self)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "lemparURL") {
        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        print("sent value:"+valueToPass)
        svc.kirimURL = valueToPass
    }
}
```

I got value to pass from tableView print, I also got sent value from prepareForSeque print.

in second ViewController I try to get parameter:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchbar: UITextField!
var todoItem: TodoItem = TodoItem(itemName: "")
var kirimURL :String!
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (self.searchbar.text != "") {
        self.todoItem = TodoItem(itemName: self.searchbar.text!)
    }
}
```

in viewDidLoad I add:

```
self.searchbar.delegate = self;
```

and in viewDidAppear I code this to get the parameter:

```
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
self.searchbar.delegate = self;
print("passed value from first viewController:"+kirimURL)
```

but I did not get kirimURL value (passed value). lemparURL seque already correct. How to correct this?

if sent parameter directly from func tableView I add this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchview") as! ViewController
viewController1.kirimURL = valueToPass
self.presentViewController(viewController1, animated: true , completion: nil)
```

Comment: why    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

Comment: var kirimURL :String! to var kirimURL :String()

Comment: I don't see anything that it should not work, But you can try to navigate programmatically maybe that way it will work, if you want i can write the code for you to navigate programmatically ?

Comment: i have also same problem above coding format but its not pass the value, so i have pass the value using `pushViewController` method programatically, its working for me

Comment: refer this link http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: @PKT use String() is wrong

Comment: @Iyyappan Ravi, that link show same answer like this question, it is just Obj-C version of this question.

Comment: @Muhammad Yawar Ali, I read navigate programatically from tableView function to sent parameter and after try it, it did not work. Did your navigate programatically different?

Comment: Can you share that code ?

Comment: @Muhammad Yawar Ali, I refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315133/swift-pass-uitableviewcell-label-to-new-viewcontroller

Comment: Can you share complete code of destination controller ?

Comment: @Muhammad Yawar Ali, I update the question on last line with add : if sent parameter directly from func tableView I add this. on destination controller, I just want to get the value on viewdidappear.

Comment: I said to add destination controller code this one is alright.