# Array not storing values

Tags: arrays, parse-platform, charts, swift2

I'm getting values back from a parse backend and using them to make an array but nothing is getting stored in it. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The line: let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i) gives back "index is out of range"

```
    var fattyArray: [Double] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let innerQuery = PFUser.query()
    innerQuery!.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: "VTieywDsZj")
    let query = PFQuery(className: "BodyFat")
    query.whereKey("UserID", matchesQuery: innerQuery!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (percentages: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Successful, \(percentages!.count) retrieved")
            if let percentage = percentages as [PFObject]! {
                for percentage in percentages! {
                    print(percentage["BodyFatPercentage"])
         self.fattyArray.append(percentage["BodyFatPercentage"].doubleValue)
                    print(self.fattyArray)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("\(error?.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    let unitsSold = fattyArray

    setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

}

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. One problem is that `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` runs asynchronously, i.e. `fattyArray` doesn't have values appended until later. You should move that code that calls `setChart` into the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` closure.

   ```
   query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { percentages, error in
       if error == nil {
           // build your array like you did in your question

           // but when done, call `setChart` here

           let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
           let unitsSold = fattyArray

           setChart(months, values: unitsSold)
       } else {
           print("\(error?.userInfo)")
       }
   }

   // but not here

   // let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
   // let unitsSold = fattyArray
   //
   // setChart(months, values: unitsSold)
   ```
2. Your `setChart` routine is giving you a "index is out of range" error because you are iterating through `dataPoints`, but looking up values in the `values` array. I see nothing here that guarantees that `months` has the same number of entries in it as `fattyArray`.

   Clearly, if you fix that first point, you have a better chance that it will work (because you'll actually not be generating the chart until after the data was entirely retrieved), but I still don't see anything here that guarantees that `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` will return at least six entries.

Comment: Thanks Rob! That did the trick. The thing is though I want to leave future months with no values as an incentive to keep making progress and filling them in. Is there a way to do this or do ChartDataEntries have to be pairs?

Comment: I would imagine that if your chart entry point permitted the use of optionals (e.g. `nil` value), then it seems that you could (a) retrieve the data from your database (presumably of pairs of dates and values) and then; (b) manually add data points with date but no value for those future dates. There are probably lots of different ways of handling this, but conceptually it seems like it would be possible. But it seems beyond the scope of this question...

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! So I had another issue that I searched for and found a thread you had commented on and was wondering if you wouldn't mind taking a look. I don't have a 50pt reputation yet so I can't comment on that thread (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28723081/5109162), but I did start another one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137259/uitableview-not-using-cell-as-sender/39137309#39137309