# UITableView Not Using Cell as Sender

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]I'm trying to segue and pass data (from UITableView to a UIViewController). My code is

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "IndividualAchievementsSegue" {
         let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? IndividualAchievementsViewController
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let selectedRow = AchievementsTable.indexPathForCell(cell)!.row
         destination!.viaSegue = achievements[selectedRow]
        print(selectedRow)
    }
}
```

but the line let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell is throwing

> Could not cast value of type 'ProgramName.AchievementsViewController' to 'UITableViewCell'

I have also tried

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "IndividualAchievementsSegue" {
         let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? IndividualAchievementsViewController
         let selectedRow = AchievementsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
         destination!.viaSegue = achievements[selectedRow]
        print(selectedRow)
    }
}
```

That fails because it finds nil unwrapping the optional during `achievements[selectedRow]` since that apparently gives me a nil from `let selectedRow = AchievementsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your segue is connected with your `AchievementsViewController` to `IndividualAchievementsViewController` instead of `UITableViewCell` to `IndividualAchievementsViewController`. Check in the storyboard for that and correct the segue with `TableCell` to `IndividualAchievementsViewController`.

Comment: I think you're right, but the weird thing is I created the segue by clicking and dragging from the prototype cell to the IndividualAchievementsViewController. However, when I examine it, by mousing over the connection dot on the side, it selects the entire view controller. Is there some trick to connecting the TableCell to the IndividualAchievementsViewController?

Comment: First remove that old segue, After that in the view hierarchy, select your `TableCell` press `ctrl` along with that and drag it to the `IndividualAchievementsViewController`, hope you gey it.

Comment: Can you show the `storyboard` image after selecting the segue, also show the code of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. that will be more helpful.

Comment: Your problem is you manually also performing the segue, inside `didSelecteRowAtIndexPath`, that was the issue, remove that line or comment, and now cast `sender as! TableCell` inside `prepareForSegue` it will work.

Comment: Are you talking about         performSegueWithIdentifier("IndividualAchievementsSegue", sender: self)  ? When it's deleted PrepareForSegue doesn't get called at all

Comment: Yes I'm talking abt that :)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to go into DidSelectrowAtIndexPath and remove DeselectRowAtIndexPath, which was in there twice by accident. Then use the following

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "IndividualAchievementsSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? IndividualAchievementsViewController
        let selectedRow = AchievementsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
        destination!.viaSegue = achievements[selectedRow!]
        print(selectedRow)
    }
}
```