# How to pass TableViewCell value into new ViewController in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, uitableview

I have this JSON data

**move.json**

```
{
    "status":"ok",
    "movement":
                [
                    {
                        "refno":"REF 1",
                        "dtfrom":"2017-13-12"
                    },
                    {
                        "refno":"REF 2",
                        "dtfrom":"2017-13-13"
                    },
                    {
                        "refno":"REF 3",
                        "dtfrom":"2017-13-14"
                    },
                ]
}
```

So far, I managed to fetch the value into TableViewCell.

But my goal is to pass the value from **ViewController.swift** into **MoveDetails.swift** so the value can be display in **MoveDetails.swift**

And I have these four swift files. I'm having the problem on ViewController.swift and MoveDetails.swift. I'm not sure how to pass the value into new Controller.

The code as below.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var move: [Move]? = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchData()
    }
    func fetchData() {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/move.json")!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data,response,error)in
            if error != nil { return }

            self.move = [Move]()
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

                if let msFromJson = json["movement"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for mFromJson in msFromJson {
                        let ms = Move()
                        if let refno   = mFromJson["refno"] as? String, let dtfrom  = mFromJson["dtfrom"] as? String {
                            ms.refno        = refno
                            ms.dtfrom       = dtfrom
                        }
                        self.move?.append(ms)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch let error{ print(error)}
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "movementstatusCell", for: indexPath) as! MoveCell

        cell.refnoLbl.text          = self.move?[indexPath.item].refno
        cell.dtfromLbl.text         = self.move?[indexPath.item].dtfrom
        return cell
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.move?.count ?? 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoveDetails") as! MoveDetails

        let selectedMove = self.move?[indexPath.item]
         vc.refnoString = selectedMove.refno
        vc.dtfromString= selectedMove.dtfrom
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**MoveCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
class MoveCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dtfromLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var refnoLbl: UILabel!    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

**Move.swift** (NSObject)

```
import UIKit
class Move: NSObject {
    var refno: String?
    var dtfrom: String?
}
```

**MoveDetails.swift**

```
import UIKit
class MoveDetails: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var refnoLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dtfromLbl: UILabel!

    var refnoString: String!
    var dtfromString: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        refnoString = refnoLbl.text
        dtfromString = dtfromLbl.text
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() { super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() }
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: this has been asked several time, what links you have tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315133/swift-pass-uitableviewcell-label-to-new-viewcontroller . But i'm not sure why the value still empty on MoveDetails.swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will just have to set the properties of your `MoveDetails` view controller. And as a suggestion

- Instead of storing `refnoString` and `dtfromString` properties in  `MoveDetails`, you could just store one property of type `Move`:
- Cache `MoveDetails` view controller to reuse it
- Implement `viewDidAppear` to update the `MoveDetails` outlets

So:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,    UITableViewDataSource {

    var detailsVC : MoveDetails?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (detailsVC == nil) {
            detailsVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoveDetails") as! MoveDetails
        }
        detailsVC.move = self.move?[indexPath.item]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVC , animated: true)
    }
}
```

Then, override `viewDidAppear` in `MoveDetails` view controller and there you just fill in the values into the text label outlets.

```
class MoveDetails: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var refnoLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dtfromLbl: UILabel!

    var move:Move?

    override func func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        refnoLbl.text = move?.refno
        dtfromLbl.text = move?.dtfrom
    }
}
```

*Syntax errors cause because I currently have no Xcode available to do the checking*

Comment: viewDid load is better place to fill the text labels

Comment: @Inder but only if you always create a new `MoveDetails` view controller. If you reuse it, you better use viewDidAppear

Comment: @AndreasOetjen yes you're right and that's what `instantiateViewController` does

Comment: Can you check my code above ? @AndreasOetjen . The value still not appear on MoveDetails.swift.

Comment: @Jamilah, you did it the wrong way (should be `refnoLbl.text = refnoString` etc) - check my modified answer

Comment: I see. Let me try it first. i'll let you know

Comment: The value can be pass to MoveDetails, but when i hit back button and select different tableCell value. It capture the previous value and did not change based on the tableCell selected. . am I missing something ?

Comment: oh. my bad. i added the label into didload method ..  I changed it inside viewDidAppear and it work like a charm. Thanks . :)